# Изменить стиль с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Есть меню. При клике оно выезжает вниз. Так же есть `div` с классом `.doc-info`. Нужно переделать скрипт так, чтобы при выезде меню, у `.doc-info padding-top`: с `320px` менялся на `420px`, к примеру. И чтоб при выполнении `else`, `padding` обратно слетал на `320px`. То есть вопрос в том, как добавить через *JS* стиль `padding-top: 420px` и убрать его при повтором клике? Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

```
// TOGGLE MNU MOBILE SANDWICH
$(".toggle-mnu").click(function() {
  $(".sandwich").toggleClass("active");
}); 

$(".toggle-mnu").click(function() {
  if ($(".hidden-mnu").is(":visible")) {
    $(".hidden-mnu").slideUp();
  } else {
    $(".hidden-mnu").slideToggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Попробовал, что я делаю не так?

Comment: @YourDeveloper, указывается вот так: `$(".doc-info").css("padding-top", "100px");`

Comment: @YourDeveloper - невнимательно читаете документацию

Comment: @YourDeveloper, нельзя изменять код в вопросе под комментарии. Вы подводите пользователей, которые ответили на старую версию кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавлять можно через стандартную функцию [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
$('.my-block').click(function() {
  $(this).css('padding-top', '50px');
});
```

```css
.my-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-block"></div>
```

2. Через добавление класса [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```js
$('.my-block').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('my-block_padding-top--50px');
  // Для удаления .removeClass();
});
```

```css
.my-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.my-block_padding-top--50px {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-block"></div>
```

Comment: А реально ли адаптивность настроить через 1ый способ?
Допустим на разрешении меньше 1200 паддинг топ дается 100px
на 1000 - 50px и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $('div').toggleClass('padding');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

div.padding {padding: 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```